# show error msg for bootstrap login modal

Tags: asp.net, validation, webforms, modal-dialog

I am using bootstrap modal to create modal, that appears automatically when the user visit the home page:

At the top of `Default.aspx` I have a JavaScript code to show the modal every time the user visit the home page:

```js
$(document).ready(function () {
            $(".modal").modal('show').css({ top: "30%" });
        });
```

then i created the bootstrap modal inside an update panel, also i created a ScriptManager at the top for the update panel, below is my modal code:

```html
<asp:ScriptManager ID="ScriptManager1" runat="server"></asp:ScriptManager>
<asp:UpdatePanel ID="LoginUpdatePanel" runat="server" UpdateMode="Conditional" EnableViewState="true">
        <ContentTemplate>
            <asp:Panel ID="myModal" runat="server" class="modal fade animated zoomIn">
<div class="modal-dialog">
                    <div class="modal-content">
                        <div class="modal-header">
                            <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal" aria-hidden="true">
                                &times;</button>
                            <h4 class="modal-title">Welcome</h4>

                        </div>
                        <div class="modal-body">
                            <asp:Panel ID="login" runat="server">
                                <div class="login-form">
                                    <asp:Label ID="lblsignin" runat="server"><h4>Sign In</h4></asp:Label>
                                    <asp:Label ID="lblMsg" CssClass="text-danger" runat="server"></asp:Label>
                                    <div class="form-group">
                                        <asp:TextBox ID="tbEmail" runat="server" CssClass="form-control" placeholder="Your Email Address"></asp:TextBox>
                                    </div>
                                    <div class="form-group">
                                        <asp:TextBox ID="tbPassword" runat="server" CssClass="form-control" placeholder="Your Password" TextMode="Password"></asp:TextBox>
                                    </div>
                                    <div class="row">
                                        <div class="col-md-6 col-xs-12">
<asp:CheckBox ID="chkRemember" runat="server" CssClass="text-danger" Text=" Remember me" Visible="false" />
                                        </div>
                                    </div>
                                </div>
                                <br />
                            </asp:Panel>
                        </div>
                        <div class="modal-footer">
                            <a href="register.aspx" class="pull-left">Create Account</a>

                            <asp:Button runat="server" ID="btnLogin" Text="Login" class="btn btn-default"
                                OnClick="btnLogin_Click" UseSubmitBehavior="false" CausesValidation="true" />

                            <button type="button" class="btn btn-default" data-dismiss="modal">
                                Close</button>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </asp:Panel>
        </ContentTemplate>
    </asp:UpdatePanel>
```

When the user enter valid information the login process work perfectly and redirect the user to the users account home page and this is my C# code :

```html
  protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(Session["User"] as string))
    {
        //check session user is already logged in then hide the modal 
        myModal.Visible = false;
    }
    else
    {

        myModal.Visible = true;

    }
}

protected void btnLogin_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {

        string email = tbEmail.Text.ToString();
        string pass = tbPassword.Text.ToString();
        if (email != "" && pass != "")
        {
             //check user authentication using the method isauthenticated in my UsersList class
            if (UsersList.isAuthenticated(email, pass))
            {
                Session["User"] = email;
                Response.Redirect("~/Account.aspx");
            }
            else
            {
                lblMsg.Text = "Wrong User name or Password";
            }
        }
        else
        {
            lblMsg.Text = "All Field are Required";
        }
    }
```

My Problem is when the user enter wrong data or keep fields empty the login form inside the modal disappear without generating an error msg inside the lblMsg.Text

This is picture of the modal before login process:

[image: the default page]

instead of getting error when user enter wrong data this is what i'am  getting the background still disabled with black screen but the login form disappear:

[image]

Can any one help me please the generate an error msg inside the lblMsg if login failed ?

Answer (score 0):

I'm not entirly sure, but I think your problem is the update panel.

When you hit the login_btn and set the error message in case of a wrong password, your '$(document).ready(function ()' isn't executed anymore.

Clicking on the login button tells bootstrap to unload the modal, but your partial update does not trigger the show function any more because the page insn't reloaded. Only a partial update takes place and the document.ready isn't triggerd. So your bootstrap modal isn't shown any more.

Is the update panel realy needed here? Whithout I think it will work ok.

In case it is needed, you need to execute a bit of javascript code to on partial postback so the modal is shown again.